# Pandas find last non NAN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where the columns are dates and each row is an independent time series.

I try to get the last value of each row using the following:

```
df['last'] =  df.iloc[:,-1]
```

However some rows have NAN values in the last column.

How can I get the last non NAN value in a row?

Comment: Are you after [last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) ?

Comment: no not the last index, the last value, in which ever column it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get last non `NaN` value in each row of a dataframe:

```
df['last_value'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1] 
print (df)
```

Comment: For a `row` with a number between `NaN`s, e.g. `35  NaN   40  NaN`, it returns `NaN`. I expected it to return `40` in this case.