# Find last non-NaN value along axis in sorted multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking at some 3D ocean temperature data (time, depth, lon, lat), and would like to extract the value at the lowest depth to create a 2D map of the temperature at the ocean floor.

The ocean floor is a mask that creates somewhat of a sorted array along the depth axis with all NaN values concentrated at the end of axis 1.

Some sample code to replicate this:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.random.rand(6,50,300,360)*100
A.ravel()[np.random.choice(A.size, 10000000, replace=False)] = np.nan
A.sort(axis=1)
```

Then, following [Getting the last non-nan index of a sorted numpy matrix or pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111052/getting-the-last-non-nan-index-of-a-sorted-numpy-matrix-or-pandas-dataframe), I get an array that contains the index of the final non-NaN element along axis 1:

```
lv=(~np.isnan(A)).sum(axis=1)-1
```

Now the tricky part is extracting the values from axis 1 of **A** using **lv** (the array of elements I want to extract). 
So far, my best method (which does work) is do create an empty array of appropriate size and filling it in element-wise:

```
B=np.zeros(lv.shape,dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(x):
            B[i,j,k]=A[i,lv[i,j,k],j,k]
```

However this is quite slow; unreasonably so for the amount of data on which I am looking to use this (many TB worth).

Any ideas on how to streamline this final stage (like in [Pandas find last non NAN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646986/pandas-find-last-non-nan-value), but for numpy)? 
I'm thinking something along the lines of (although I realise this doesn't even make sense):

```
B=A[:,lv[:],:,:]
```

I've also tried variations of np.take, np.take_along_axis, and np.choose with no success.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy's [take_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) should work for this. The last step can be expressed as follows:

```
B = np.take_along_axis(A, lv[:,None,:,:], axis=1).squeeze()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked!
I swear I tried pretty much this, but I must have been slightly off in the syntax.

Comment: Sure thing. As an aside, the `dtype` of `B` will default to the `dtype` of `A` (in my case `np.float64`). If you need `B` to have 32 bit precision you can recast it with `B.astype(np.float32)`.